# CDS View Consumption in ABAP Open SQL

Tags: abap, opensql, cds

As part of ABAP 7.50, SAP has imposed restriction on direct consumption of CDS view in ABAP OPEN SQL select query, through strict mode. So that, I am getting P3 Error in ATC checks.

I would like to know is there any other way to get data from CDS view in ABAP report?

Comment: Why is it an issue to write ABAP SQL in strict mode? It's almost the same syntax as non-strict mode. Moreover, priority 3 messages are not errors, these are more like recommendations, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use the select from SQL view created in @AbapCatalogue.sqlViewname.

Comment: It will still show that in P3 message in ATC check.